# Is there an option to pass "paranoia mode" to encfs from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

I want to pass the `p` option to `encfs` from the command line to set "paranoia mode," and alias the command to something else so users can work with it without knowing details.

Is there an option to pass "paranoia mode" from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is enough to open a text file and type "p" in it then redirect stdin to it:

> encfs /.encfs /ecfs

as simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo p | encfs ~/.encfs ~/encfs
```

```
encfs ~/.encfs ~/encfs <<< "p"
```